# Performing A String Operation in a -replace Expression

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make using of String.Substring() to replace every string with its  substring from a certain position. I'm having a hard time figuring out the right syntax for this.

```
$dirs = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $path | Format-Table -AutoSize -HideTableHeaders -Property @{n='Mode';e={$_.Mode};width=50}, @{n='LastWriteTime';e={$_.LastWriteTime};width=50}, @{n='Length';e={$_.Length};width=50}, @{n='Name';e={$_.FullName -replace "(.:.*)", "*($(str($($_.FullName)).Substring(4)))*"}} | Out-String -Width 40960
```

I'm referring to the following expression

```
e={$_.FullName -replace "(.:.*)", "*($(str($($_.FullName)).Substring(4)))*"}}
```

The substring from the 4th character isn't replacing the Full Name of the path.
The paths in question are longer than 4 characters.

The output is just empty for the Full Name when I run the script.
Can someone please help me out with the syntax

**EDIT**
The unaltered list of strings (as `Get-ChildItem` recurses) would be

```
D:\this\is\where\it\starts
D:\this\is\where\it\starts\dir1\file1
D:\this\is\where\it\starts\dir1\file2
D:\this\is\where\it\starts\dir1\file3
D:\this\is\where\it\starts\dir1\dir2\file1
```

The `$_.FullName` will therefore take on the value of each of the strings listed above.
Given an input like *D:\this\is* or *D:\this\is\where*, then I'm computing the length of this input (including the delimiter `\`) and then replacing `$_.FullName` with a substring beginning from the nth position where *n* is the length of the input.

If input is D:\this\is, then length is 10.
Expected output is

```
\where\it\starts
\where\it\starts\dir1\file1
\where\it\starts\dir1\file2
\where\it\starts\dir1\file3
\it\starts\dir1\dir2\file1
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and give an example of what the unaltered string is and what the desired string is? Having a hard time understanding exactly what you are looking to do.

Comment: In addition, please explain [what you are trying to achieve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). It looks like you are trying to build some kind of summary report; maybe there's better a way.

Comment: If you just want to remove the leading ``D:\`` you should do exactly that: `$_.FullName -replace '^.:\\'`. If you want to remove a particular parent path you could do this: `$_.FullName -replace ('^' + [regex]::Escape($parent))`. If you must use a fixed length you could do this: `$_.FullName -replace '^.{4}'`.

Comment: So do you just want to remove the drive and the first path of "$Path"? You can make that dynamic by doing ".Substring($Path.Length)"

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers, it was so simple :), being a newbie to Powershell and not all that familiar with regex, I guess I decided to use the most complicated solution to achieve this. If you post this as an answer, I can mark this as SOLVED :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove a particular prefix from a string you can do so like this:

```
$prefix = 'D:\this\is'
...
$_.FullName -replace ('^' + [regex]::Escape($prefix))
```

To remove a prefix of a given length you can do something like this:

```
$len = 4
...
$_.FullName -replace "^.{$len}"
```

Answer (score 0):

When having trouble, simplify:

This function will do what you are apparently trying to accomplish:

```
Function Remove-Parent {
  param(
    [string]$Path, 
    [string]$Parent) 
  $len = $Parent.length
  $Path.SubString($Len)
}
```

The following is not the way you likely would use it but does demonstrate that the function returns the expected results:

```
@'
D:\this\is\where\it\starts
D:\this\is\where\it\starts\dir1\file1
D:\this\is\where\it\starts\dir1\file2
D:\this\is\where\it\starts\dir1\file3
D:\this\is\where\it\starts\dir1\dir2\file1
'@ -split "`n" | ForEach-Object { Remove-Parent $_ 'D:\This\Is'  }

# Outputs
\where\it\starts
\where\it\starts\dir1\file1
\where\it\starts\dir1\file2
\where\it\starts\dir1\file3
\where\it\starts\dir1\dir2\file1
```

Just call the function with the current path ($_.fullname) and the "prefix" you are expecting to remove.

The function above is doing this strictly on 'length' but you could easily adapt it to match the actual string with either a string replace or a regex replace.

```
Function Remove-Parent {
  param(
    [string]$Path, 
    [string]$Parent
  )
  $remove = [regex]::Escape($Parent)
  $Path -replace "^$remove"
}
```

The output was the same as above.